# How to use time in FQL where clause

Tags: time, facebook-fql, where-clause, status

I have the following query to select statuses from the friends of a user in the last week:

```
SELECT status_id, uid, message, time from status where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND time > 1366038021
```

(the 1366038021 was one week ago from the time I did the query)

This returns 7 results, but it's missing the two latest from one of my friends (which occurred after the time I'm filtering on.)  If I remove the time clause, I get the two I am missing, for a total of 9 results.  Their times are **1366660761** and **1366662471**, which are **> 1366038021** so they should always show up, but they don't.  If I change the clause to be `time > 0` it also returns the 9 results.  If I change to `time > 1` I get an empty result set.  If I change it to `time > 1366138021` I get the desired 9 results...

Now, I've read many other posts explaining the way that FB filters out the results.  I understand that if I had a limit X in there, it would grab X results, filter out by visibility and return Y results instead of X.  I can't see how that is happening here.  I don't have a limit in there for one thing (and even putting one in with a large number changes nothing.)  Also, I am using a test account for this, and I only have 2-3 friends with a few statuses each.  Therefore I don't have some large result set that is being filtered.

Has anyone ran into something like this before?  Am I missing something?